# sc command with wildcard

Tags: service, windows

I have a commercial software that installed a lot of service started with the same prefix, i.e

`Product Service A, Product Service B ...`

Now I need to stop all these services, but sc doesn't seem to support wildcard, is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Powershell and toy around with `get-service`, `start-service` and `stop-service`. It should be possible to either feed a complete list to `stop-service`, either via a pipe or a loop over from the output from `get-service`.

Comment: That's cool, I'm going to deploy it today